# Property 'artist' does not exist on type 'ArtistItemsComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

So I'm new to Angular, and following an Angular5 course on LinkedIn.
I'm trying to create a subcomponent named artist-items, and have created the HTML and TS files for it.

Okay, apologies for posting a lot of code, because I'm a newbie and I'm confused as to what might be the problem here.

I'm trying to create a subcomponent named my-artists, wherein I add a part of HTML to it, and try to link it to the main HTML, I accept an object named `artist` (from a for loop, fetching data from a JSON file) in the main component HTML, where the `selector` of the subcomponent is present.

Following is the error I get:

```
Error: src/app/artist-items/artist-items.component.html:3:107 - error TS2339: Property 'artist' does not exist on type 'ArtistItemsComponent'.      

3       style="width:70px;" [src]="'./assets/images/' + artist.shortname + '_tn.jpg'" alt="{{ 'Photo of ' + artist.name }}">
                                                                                                            ~~~~~~

  src/app/artist-items/artist-items.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './artist-items.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ArtistItemsComponent.
```

I've only posted a part of the error, because I got a few more errors in the same format, that there's an error in my subcomponent's HTML.
I'm assuming that there might have been a wrong format in the object at my main HTML, where the subcomponent's selector lies.
Please help me out!

Main Component (App.Component) TS file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [
    `
      .list-group-item:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-top: 0;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  query: string;
  artists: any;

  showArtist(e:any,item: any) {
    this.query = item.name;
    item.highlight = !item.highlight;
  }

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {
    this.query = '';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<any>('../assets/data.json').subscribe( data => {
      this.artists = data;
    })
  }

}
```

Main (App Component) HTML:

```
<div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start"
            *ngFor="let artist of artists"
            (click)="showArtist(artist)"
            [style.backgroundColor]="artist.highlight ? '#EEE' : '#FFF'">



            <app-artist-items [artist]="artist" ></app-artist-items> **THIS IS THE SUBCOMPONENT**



          </a><!-- link -->
</div><!-- list-group -->
```

Main (App Module) TS:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { ArtistItemsComponent } from './artist-items/artist-items.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ArtistItemsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

artist-items-component TS:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist-items',
  templateUrl: './artist-items.component.html',
  inputs: ['artist']
})
export class ArtistItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

artist-items-component HTML:

```
<div class="media">
    <img class="mr-3 rounded align-self-center img-fluid" 
      style="width:70px;" [src]="'./assets/images/' + artist.shortname + '_tn.jpg'" alt="{{ 'Photo of ' + artist.name }}">
    <div class="media-body align-self-center">
      <h5 class="m-0">{{ artist.name }}</h5>
      {{ artist.reknown }}
    </div><!-- media body -->
</div><!-- media -->
```

Comment: You're trying to access properties of `artist`, but there's no such thing as an `artist` property on your component's class. Adding something like `artist = { name: 'Pablo Picaso', reknown: 10 }` to `artist-items.component.ts` will make it work.

Comment: Hi, I have a JSON file, which I didn't post here. I have imported the 'Artists' from the file in the main TS using a GET request, using ngOnInit. Then I looped each artist in the Main HTML using *ngFor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. You are **missing the declaration of the `artist` variable in `ArtistItemsComponent`**.

From your scenario, you are passing the `artist` object from the `AppComponent` (parent component) to `ArtistItemsComponent` (child component), you need to use [`@Input()` decorator](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component) for the `artist` declaration as well.

```js
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

export class ArtistItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() artist: any;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qfy33u?file=src/app/artist-items/artist-items.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm able to get the output clearly now.
You've been extremely helpful!